# OnAfterRenderAsync not triggered

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the OnAfterRenderAsync method in the Blazor.

I can't seem to find a solution after trying multiple options and looking through Microsoft docs, I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't figure out what the issue is.

In the code below, the OnInit function is getting called, but the render ones aren't.

```
<h1>OnInit & OnInitAsync Demo</h1>

@foreach (var item in EventType)
{
    @item
    <hr />
}

@code{
    List<string> EventType = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EventType.Add("Initilaized");
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        EventType.Add("OnAfterRender is called");
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        EventType.Add("OnAfterRenderAsync is called");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

This my .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And this is my _Host.cshtml

```
<app>
     <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</app>
```

I've also tried it this way

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

Why aren't the events being triggered?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following line to the end of body (not head) in _Host.cshtml:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (.NET 8.0.101) the page was missing the following line:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

Then it triggers the event on the server.

Answer (score 1):

if you used server mode, maybe you forgot MapBlazorHub in Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
```

Comment: I don't known why, I just met the same problem and I found that I forgot MapBlazorHub. After using it, everything turned to be right.

Answer (score 1):

As @user13925483 mentioned it is needed to add:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

at the end of the _Host file.

But the question is why.
From Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync):

> OnAfterRender and OnAfterRenderAsync aren't called during the
> prerendering process on the server. The methods are called when the
> component is rendered interactively after prerendering. When the app
> prerenders:
>
> 1. The component executes on the server to produce some static HTML markup in the HTTP response. During this phase, OnAfterRender and
>    OnAfterRenderAsync aren't called.
> 2. When the Blazor script (blazor.webassembly.js or blazor.server.js) start in the browser, the component is restarted in an interactive
>    rendering mode. After a component is restarted, OnAfterRender and
>    OnAfterRenderAsync are called because the app isn't in the
>    prerendering phase any longer.

And even when you create empty Blazor server project, you can find in the `Pages/_Host.cshtml` this script line at the end of the HTML body:

```
@page "/"
@namespace WebApplication6Server.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebApplication6Server</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="WebApplication6Server.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>  @* <-------- this line *@
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are saying it is not "triggering" `OnAfterRenderAsync` because you don't see an event listed on the page for it?

That would be because there is no render automatically after `OnAfterRenderAsync` - to avoid looping.

You can do this - because the condition ensures it will only happen once - to trigger another render and you will then see the event listed on the page.

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  EventType.Add("OnAfterRenderAsync is called");
  if (firstRender) 
  {
    StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was using:

```
app.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization();
```

adding AllowAnonymous to my _Host file did nothing.  As a temporary fix I had to remove `.RequireAuthorization` pipe as I'm away on a trip and can't connect to Identity Server to provide a better answer.  The page loads fine but this event OnAfterRenderAsync will not fire until I remove `.RequireAuthorization`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but in the component I changed my rendermode:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

Now, it's working very well.

Comment: This was it for me.
I assume this will be a very common reason in .Net 8 and the new Blazor auto rendering modes.

Comment: Yes... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0