# Can a Blazor element access data in a peer element?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have broken out my razor page as follows:

```
@page "/Manager/ListCampaigns"

<OrganizationFilter SearchAsync="@SearchCampaigns"></OrganizationFilter>

<OrganizationGrid ListOrganizations="@MatchingCampaigns"></OrganizationGrid>
```

My problem is that `<OrganizationFilter>` has the data that `OrganizationGrid.ListOrganizations` needs. So is there some way to do the equivilent of:

```
<OrganizationGrid ListOrganizations="@OrganizationFilter.MatchingCampaigns"></OrganizationGrid>
```

Or do I need to pass it up to the parent and from the parent down to the other, using `bind-MatchingCampaigns`?

---

**Update**

I got some very good answers from @MrCakaShaunCurtis and @BrianParker below. And I trust their depths of knowledge over my still being a newbie in Blazor. But with that said...

1. `[CascadingParameter]` - The parent component declares this parameter and the children each access it. So child #1 sets it, child #2 see's it has changed and re-renders. That's clean, simple, it works, and is dependent on the variable change triggering a re-render which is something we use throughout Blazor.
2. Add a scoped service. The DI object has a DataChanged event handler they register with. So child 1 calls the delegate and child 2 receives the call. This is a bit more complex and allows others access to this private conversation (i.e. potential bugs). But it's message based which I prefer all things being equal.
3. The parent has a public event DataChanged() that the first child can call. When it calls that, the parent then calls the second child's DataChanged() method. So chained message passing. Moderately simple, clean, and 100% message based.

I went with choice #3. Why?

Choice #2 I think is great where needed. But for this situation it strikes me as overly complex.

Choice #1 uses functionality core to Blazor, re-rendering on a data change. Both `[CascadingParameter]` and the concept of data being observed are new to me and so it's not my first choice.

With that said, I need to learn to make use of these fundamentals. So I have it on my ver 1.1 list to redo this with a `[CascadingParameter]` so I learn to take this approach.

And thank you to @MrCakaShaunCurtis and @BrianParker - I get solutions from you two which is helpful. But I also learn more about Blazor from you two which is gigantic.

Comment: There are 3 ways I can think of to do this. 1. A parent Orchestration Component, 2. A common cascading value, 3. A service that is injected into both.

Comment: My solution is @BrianParker's 2.  A context class that either the presentation layer or component [if you have a dirty design] holds and the top level component cascades.  For instance I have a `ListContext` for list pages that marshals the paging, ordering and filtering of the displayed list.

Comment: You should never pass references to components around.  You have no control over their lifecycle.  You could easily have a reference to a disposed copy of a component the Renderer is no longer using.

Comment: @BrianParker What I ended up doing is creating delegates where the child calls the parent and from that the parent calls the other child. So two step message passing. Any thoughts on that? (So no `@bind-`)

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I didn't try the common cascading parameter because I didn't know if changing it would cause the component to re-render. So went with message passing. With that said, I'm open to alternatives...

Comment: @DavidThielen - Not a nice solution  - "What a tangled web we weave".  See this answer on how to do the cascading state - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75203393/13065781,

Comment: Ill share a little trick ive been working on for state notification give me a few minutes. An easy way to do no 3. (once setup)

Comment: @HH I think two lists would be a very strong argument for CascadingParameters. Because better 2 parameters than two services or two sets of DataChanged calls. (Although maybe you could do 1 service with two event handlers if you prefer that route). ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using this lately. I create a generic notification service. I use inheritance to make a version for each scope type.

The beauty of this is once setup you can easily create as many as you would like without having to register more services.

The `<T>` can be a empty class if you wish or with properties so you can be granular for your listener.

Generic Service

```cs
public abstract class ViewState<T> : IViewState<T>
{
    private T value;

    public T Value => value;

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;

        NotifyWatchers();
    }

    public void NotifyWatchers()
    {
        if (ViewStateChanged != null)
        {
            ViewStateChanged.Invoke(this, new ViewStateEventArgs<T>(this.value));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ViewStateEventArgs<T>> ViewStateChanged;
}

public class SingletonViewState<T> : ViewState<T>, ISingletonViewState<T> { }
public class TransientViewState<T> : ViewState<T>, ITransientViewState<T> { }
public class ScopedViewState<T> : ViewState<T>, IScopedViewState<T> { }
```

`Program.cs` Register the services for each scope type

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ISingletonViewState<>), typeof(SingletonViewState<>));
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(ITransientViewState<>), typeof(TransientViewState<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IScopedViewState<>), typeof(ScopedViewState<>));
```

Notifying Component.

```cs
[Inject]
private IScopedViewState<MessageListViewState> MessageListViewState { get; set; }

private async Task SaveMessage(EditContext editContext)
{
    ...
    MessageListViewState.NotifyWatchers();
}
```

Listener Component.

```cs
[Inject]
private IScopedViewState<MessageListViewState> MessageListViewState { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    this.MessageListViewState.ViewStateChanged += HandleViewStateChanged;
}

private void HandleViewStateChanged(object sender, ViewStateEventArgs<MessageListViewState> messageListViewStateEventArgs)
{
    quickGrid.RefreshDataAsync();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (MessageListViewState is not null)
    {
        this.MessageListViewState.ViewStateChanged -= HandleViewStateChanged;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MessageListViewState { }
```

Comment: Interesting implementation.  I like it.

Comment: I don't know if you ever used WebForms (.aspx) but I wouldn't call it ViewState.

Comment: @HH Thanks I'll take that onboard. I also don't like the name `NotifyWatchers` I will be changing that to `NotifyListeners`. This technique allows me to have multiple listeners on one page. For example, I have users, groups and messages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if this kind of solution will be the good in this situation, but it should work:

```
<OrganizationFilter SendData="SetData"/>
<OrganizationGrid Data="@Data" />

@code {

    public string Data { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public void SetData(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

OrganizationFilter.cs:

```
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> SendData { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await SendBack();
    }

    public async Task SendBack()
    {
        await SendData.InvokeAsync("example data");
    }
}
```

OrganizationGrid.cs

```
Data from Filter Component: @Data

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Data { get; set; } = string.Empty;

}
```

Comment: I think that would work if it was `@bind-Data=` instead of `Data=`. And what you have is close to what I ended up with. Thank you