Blazor state change propagation
I am writing a Blazor application that is composed of several components; for example, the UserExplorer component provides functionality to view, add, update, and remove users.
Each of these functions exists as its own component; for example:

AddUser is a form that creates a new user.
ViewUsers is a table that displays all users.

I believe that this is good practice for components as it keeps them clean and aligns with the Single Responsibility Principle, but it incurs some problems, specifically to do with state changes across components; for example, calling StateHasChanged from the AddUsers component does not update the table in the ViewUsers component.
       +-----------------+
       |   UserExplorer  |
       +-----------------+
               /\
              /  \
             /    \
            /      \  
+-------------+   +-------------+
|   AddUser   |-?>|  ViewUsers  |
+-------------+   +-------------+

Note: -?> denotes that I want changes in AddUser to propagate to ViewUsers.
If I were using a JavaScript SPA framework, like Angular, I might use something like RxJS or NgRx to solve this problem, so what I'm wondering is, does the same approach apply in Blazor, or is there something I'm missing?
Here's what I've tried so far...the following class is a simple event bus that I can publish from, and subscribe to.
For brevity, I have only included the interface here. The implementation details are superfluous, as I'm trying to identify whether conceptually, an event bus is the right approach.
public interface IEventBus {
    void Subscribe(string eventName, Action action);
    void Subscribe(string eventName, Func<Task> action);

    void Unsubscribe(string eventName, Action action);
    void Unsubscribe(string eventName, Func<Task> asyncAction);

    Task PublishAsync(string eventName);
}

Assuming that IEventBus is wired up as an injectable dependency...
services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, EventBus>();

...I can now call this from each component.
Publish from AddUser:
await eventBus.PublishAsync("user added");

Subscribe from ViewUsers:
eventBus.Subscribe("user added", async () => await LoadUsers());

Whilst this approach works and doesn't incur an enormous headache in trying to coordinate event propagation, what I want to know is:

Is this a recommended, or even good approach in the first place?
If the above is true, what should I be using, rather than rolling my own event bus?
If the above is false, what am I missing?


In this case I typically have ViewUsers display the AddUser control and set an EventCallback called something like UserAdded. When the callback is executed, I have the ViewUsers control refresh data.
This is an extra call to the server, but it ensures the user is always looking at the newest state; this will include state from other users + also exclude the edited user if they no longer match the search criteria or move the user up/down the list if a change was made to a property that the list is being ordered on.
If the ViewUsers control doesn't display the AddUser control directly, then the page that hosts both should mediate by adding AddUser.UserAdded and calling ViewUsers.Refresh(), like so (for the benefit of others, not you, you know this).
<AddUser UserAdded=@UserAdded Visible=@ShowAddUser/>
<ViewUsers @ref=ViewUsers/>

@code
{
  private ViewUsers ViewUsers = null!; // This will be set when rendered

  private async Task UserAdded()
  {
    await ViewUsers.Refresh();
  }
}


I use two approaches.

Use a Scoped Notification service for the entity.  It's generic and interface based with a boiler plate base class so you simply define an instance in DI.  Whenever you mutate or add an item, you raise the event in the service and any components with an interest have a registered handler and can update.  This approach caters for custom instances where required.  I can provide more detail if required.  This is very similar to your event bus, but restricts the implementation to a SPA session.  Any global singleton implementation needs to be very careful about registration/de-registration.

Here's a typical implementation from a project I'm currently working on:

public interface INotificationService<T>
    where T : class
{
    public event EventHandler StateChanged;
    public event EventHandler? RecordChanged;
    public void NotifyStateChanged(object? sender);
    public void NotifyRecordChanged(object? sender);
}

public class NotificationService<T> : INotificationService<T>
    where T: class
{
    public event EventHandler? StateChanged;
    public event EventHandler? RecordChanged;

    public void NotifyStateChanged(object? sender)
        => StateChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);

    public void NotifyRecordChanged(object? sender)
        => RecordChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
}

Which is then declared in DI like this:
services.AddScoped<INotificationService<DcoFeed>, NotificationService<DcoFeed>>();


Most commonly, I use dialogs for mutation pages.  Pop up a dialog from a grid page to edit a record.  If you commit that mutation you signal the update in the return value from the dialog and refresh the grid.

Here's couple of screen shot to demonstrate:



Thanks. This looks like a similar approach to what I'm suggesting. Is the scoped notification service you mentioned something that comes out of the box with Blazor, or a 3rd party dependency, or something you hand rolled?

@MatthewLayton Don't get too hung up on the terminology.  A "service" is just a class that you declare in your app code with builder.Services.AddScoped<MyClass>();  (or AddSingleton or AddTransient) Then reference it in a component's markup code with @inject MyClass MC, which you then reference as you would any class instance: MC.Notify("Hello!");  So a "nofication service" is just a class that has an event to subscribe to, and the service will call the event whenever it has new information to send out.

@Bennyboy1973 I'm aware of how services work and how they're injected. My question was more, to do with whether that service was an API provided by Blazor/Microsoft, a 3rd party API (like Rx), or hand rolled. Comparing what I've suggested to the OPs "notification service" means that mine would qualify as hand rolled, and I would prefer to use something established, if such a thing exists.

I've updated my answer with some code.  Hand rolled, but it's a common pattern used by Blazor developers.  You either use a Scoped DI instance, or if you want it scoped to a Page, create an instance in the top level component and cascade it.  Search SO for "[blazor] notification pattern" for a lot of Q&A on the subject.

You can see a simple demo of the Modal option here - https://blazr-weather-bootstrap-server.azurewebsites.net/weather

@MatthewLayton Services are built into .Net, and are simple to implement: trivially easy, once you've done it a couple of times.  I'm curious what more you are looking for that might go above and beyond the few lines of code Shaun has offered, i.e. what would qualify something as more "established" in your mind?

You can also check out this implementation by another major contributor to SO Blazor @BrianParker https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449070/13065781

@Bennyboy1973 Apologies, I didn't see any code in the post earlier. What would qualify as more "established" would be any library where the authors/maintainers have collectively come across the same problem and written a solution, rather than me having to reinvent the wheel.

I see what you're saying, but there's really no wheel here that needs to be invented.  Services make this kind of task super-simple.  I'll add an example to show you.

Here's what I consider a minimal example for your use case.  The actual service is just a couple lines of code.  Once you get used to this, you can do it all in about 2 mins.  I really don't see how adding any 3rd-party solution could make it easier than this.
I registered it as AddSingleton so you can open the two pages in separate windows.  Don't do this in production unless you want all users to get the update (you might!)
CustomUser.cs
namespace AddingUsersDemo.Code
{
    public class CustomUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}

MyUserManager.cs
namespace AddingUsersDemo.Code
{
    public class MyUserManager
    {
        public event Action<CustomUser>? OnNewUser;

        public async Task AddUser(CustomUser user)
        {
            // await SQLservice.Insert (user);
            OnNewUser?.Invoke(user);
        }
    }
}

UserAdder.razor
@page "/adder"
@using AddingUsersDemo.Code
@inject MyUserManager MU


Name <input @bind=_name />
Phone <input @bind=_phone />
<button @onclick=AddUser >Add </button>

@code {
    string _name = "";
    string _phone = "";

    async Task AddUser ()
    {
        var newUser = new CustomUser() { Name = _name, Phone = _phone };
        await MU.AddUser(newUser);
    }
}

UserViewer.razor
@page "/viewer"
@using AddingUsersDemo.Code
@inject MyUserManager MU

@foreach (var user in Users)
{
    <div>@user.Name</div>
    <div>@user.Phone</div>
    <hr/>
}
@code {
    List<CustomUser> Users = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MU.OnNewUser += HandleNewUser;
    }
    async void HandleNewUser(CustomUser user)
    {
        Users.Add(user);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        MU.OnNewUser -= HandleNewUser;
    }
}

Program.cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyUserManager>();


"I registered it as AddSingleton so you can open the two pages in separate windows. Don't do this in production unless you want all users to get the update (you might!)"...that was very enlightening!

I actually discovered that by accident and was very excited when I realized what it means-- it allows you to broadcast god messages ("This site will close for maintenance in 5 mins. . . ") to all users, to do cross-user chatting, to have users edit documents together, etc.
